# Slingscold wingpanel integration

Tags: wingpanel, slingshot

Slingshot is the only aspect of the pantheon DE that bugs me a little.

In the left-top corner you can see the "Applications" button, it opens slingshot.

I would want that this wingpanel button opens Slingscold instead of Slingshot.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it's not quite what you asked for, but you could add a "hot corner" for opening slingscold, whenever your pointer is top left. That's what I do at least :)

Comment: I know that is not what you want: but in what are those programs different?

Comment: Thanks for the "hot corner" solution. Having to look at Slingshot makes me want to gouge my eyeballs out. It's so out of place in the context of elementary os and what I believe their values are, it makes the OS look like a cheaply made fisher price tablet IMO. It doesn't even have a full-screen option.